# How to globally set all URL's in a Jekyll site to open in a new browser tab?

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions, jekyll-theme

I am using the Jekyll [minima](https://github.com/jekyll/minima) theme for my website. I currently have `{:target="_blank"}` added after each link. However, is there a setting that I can easily tweak (perhaps in `_config.yml`?) that will apply `{:target="_blank"}`to every link on my site without having to manually include it every time?

Edit: Just came across the [Jekyll Target Blank](https://github.com/keithmifsud/jekyll-target-blank) plugin, created by GitHub user keithmifsud. Currently reading through the documentation to see if this could achieve what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I am using the plugin you mentioned and so far it seems to work just as you intend.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that [jekyll-target-blank](https://github.com/keithmifsud/jekyll-target-blank) works wonders.

Just add it to your Gemfile:

```bash
gem 'jekyll-target-blank'
```

Then list it in your site's `_config.yml`:

```yaml
plugins:
  - jekyll-target-blank
```

Then finally run `bundle install` and all external links should open in a new tab now!